# statsmodel OLS p-values vs sklearn's feature_selection.f_regression

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, statsmodels

Basically, I ran a normal LinearRegression() with sklearn. I got the coefficients no problem. But to get the p-values, I have to use sklearn's feature_selection.f_regression. I then tried to cross check it with StatsModel OLS. This is where I got a problem.

Coefficients:
They are the same from sklearn's LinearRegression() and StatsModel's OLS.

P-Values:
TOTALLY DIFFERENT between the two. I've triple checked that I fed the same information into both models. If I made a mistake by feeding different data into the two models, my coefficients would not have been the same.

So my question is, why are the p-values different for the two?

Comment: There are [known differences between these two libraries' linear regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146804/difference-between-statsmodel-ols-and-scikit-linear-regression).